# Use "User-Defined-Functions" in Caret

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, cross-validation, r-caret, training-data

I am working with functions and fits built by my own in R. It is possible to use any of these in Caret with the train function, as a "method", instead of the functions of the Caret's built-in library (example: "lm")?. In other words, it is possible to use a "user-defined" function, adjustment or fit in Caret to train those ones?
In case of a negative answer: Does anyone know a simple way of doing a train and CV/K-Folds CV in R using user-defined functions/fits?

I have tried functions of the Caret's built-in library and it works!

```
CV <- train(Y~X,
            data = data,
            method = "myXY.fit",
            trControl=trainControl(method = "cv",
                                   number=5,
                                   savePredictions = TRUE,
                                   verboseIter = TRUE)
            )
```

I get this message:
Error: Model myXY.fit is not in caret's built-in library